# Fail to train SVM when got "warning: class label 0 specified in weight is not found"

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I found this problem just by accident(when I use K-fold to train huge data)

The problem that I have is similar with issue [issue5150](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5150). However, when I get this warning "class label 0 specified in weight is not found", I can not even get the model(The kernel is linear).

The x, y and w can be copied from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9494

And here is my code and errors:

```
>>> clf = SVC(C=0.5,class_weight='balanced',kernel='linear')
>>> clf.fit(x, y, sample_weight=w)
warning: class label 0 specified in weight is not found
SVC(C=0.5, cache_size=200, class_weight='balanced', coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> clf.coef_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 488, in coef_
    coef = self._get_coef()
  File "/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 707, in _get_coef
    if sp.issparse(coef[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: i can reproduce the error. It is a bug.